# Mysqli outputting 10 random rows

Tags: php, mysql, random, mysqli

I would like to retrieve 10 random rows from my database, each time i refresh the page i want the random rows to change.

I have made a query and a while loop to output all 10 results however i am just getting a blank page in return, there is no errors, nothing....

Its probably something silly i have missed out, but i just cant find it.

Here is my PHP :

```
<?php
include '../dbconnect.php';


$res = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM messages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
while($row=$res->fetch_array())
{

 echo $row['id'] . "<br>";

}


?>
```

Thankyou for any help

Comment: is the <br>-tag printed?

Comment: No its not, i also just changed it to text and its still not printed

Comment: either there is an error or there is no data in the table. did you enable the printing of all errors?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to output the results from a empty table, sorry

Comment: Voting to close a typo/non-reproducible error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include '../dbconnect.php';


$res = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM messages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
while($row=$res->fetch_array())
{
 $number = rand(1,10);
 echo $row['$number'] . "<br>";

}


?>
```

$row is an array, and id already is in there because of your query

Comment: `'$number'` is not a variable but exactly that, which wont be found. There is only 1 column being selected so you can't random select `1` to `10` (it would be 0 to 9 as well).